# unable to understand jdbc getExportedKeys() behaviour

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to fetch Foregin key in a table using this code

```
DatabaseMetaData dbm=conn.getMetaData();
List options=new ArrayList();
esultSet rslt=null;
rslt=dbm.getExportedKeys(null, schema, tableName);
while(rslt.next()){
                options.add(rslt.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"));
            }
```

My doubt is some time I am getting same column name of this table twice or thrice or many times in the resultset? Why so?
How can I find that this particular column in resultset is related to which table primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that column appears in more than one foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

getExportedKeys is not really "get-foreign-keys"... getExportedKeys returns data about the fields in which this table's primary key acts as foreign key. That is, the rows ARE NOT foreing keys for the table passed as parameter. Perhaps you might use getImportedKeys...